# Are some typos permissible if submitting a manuscript for potential publication?

Tags: publications, journals

As the title states are some typos expected if submitting a manuscript for potential publication? I recently submitted an article to a journal and after re-reading it just now (2 weeks later) realized there are 5-6 minor typos. A few typos are misplaced commas, but some are grammatical errors.

For example: "Based results..." which should read "Based on results..."

The article is currently under peer review. Will these small typos be detrimental to my chances of publication?

Answer (score 8):

This stuff happens, and everyone knows it. If this is on a single page, then it looks unprofessional. If it's 5 or 6 throughout the entire manuscript, then this is reasonable and to be expected. Keep track of these and make the changes as part of your revision once the paper comes back from the reviewers. In your reply to the reviewers, just mention "During revision, I have also taken the liberty to fix a small number of typos and grammar errors that had unfortunately made their way into the original manuscript".

Comment: Also depends on the typo : change one letter on “duck” and it **will** be noticed...

Comment: Yikes, would you really use such a long sentence just to say that you fixed some typos? I usually write: "Fixed typos".

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano using 17 words when two will do is a skill :) I do agree with you though.

Comment: Well, look, I'm German -- I can't help but being verbose and thorough! ;-)

Comment: I would not even mention that typos were fixed unless the reviewers pointed them out. Typos are usually only of interest to the copy-editor.